# Android Studio compileSdkVersion 25 не работает на Android 4

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk, gradle, build, android-support-library

После обновления библиотек Android Studio столкнулся с тем, что программы не запускаются на Android-4.04, на Android-6 идёт нормально.
Создаю самый простой проект (Empty Activity).
В автоматически формируемом `build.gradle`:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1
```

На устройстве сразу вылет. 
Studio пишет: *Could not find method android.support.v4.app...* и кучу других ошибок *Could not find method...*

Меняю:

```
compileSdkVersion 23
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1
```

Запускается нормально. Получается, версия 25 не поддерживает Андроид-4 или я чего-то не понимаю?

Answer (score 1):

Проблема оказалась в том, что я обновлял библиотеки (SDK), но не обновлял саму Android Studio (стояла версия 1.4).

После обновления до последней Android Studio 3.0.1 новые библиотеки заработали нормально

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте добавить следующую строчку

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
```

Перезагрузите Android Studio